# how to differentiate an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

the integral is of the form below
$$
\frac {d {\int y(x, t)h(x) dx}}{dy(x, t)}
$$
what does the differentiation give? $h(x)$

and what about 
$$
\frac {d {\int y(x, t)h(y(x,t)) dx}}{dy(x, t)}
$$
gives $h(y(x,t))+ h^{'}(y(x,t))$

How should I calculate these and what rule should I follow?